# Как зафиксировать промотку страницы, чтобы страница не поднималась после перезагрузки?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть,допустим, страница с шапкой-меню и контентом, который меняется при нажатии кнопок этого меню и страница перезагружается и при этом поднимается на самый верх шапки

```
<div class="header">
  <nav>
    <a href="/contacts">
    <a href="/users">
    <a href="/places">
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Как зафиксировать промотку страницы, чтобы страница не поднималась так высоко после перезагрузки, а была хотя бы на 20rem ниже.

Answer (score -1):

Яваскипт не нужен для этого(судя по меткам вы его предлагаете). Используйте якоря, сразу за шапкой `<a name="top"></a>` и к ссылкам добавить #top
В этом случае если пользователь пришел с поисковика например то покажется шапка, если из  меню то так как вы хотите.